# How to merge two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am looking to merge two dictionaries with the key as months and the values as a list of 12 values in both dictionaries. How do I merge the two dictionaries so that it does not sort into alpha order based on key. I simply want to add my second dictionary (with months June - December as keys) onto the end of my first dictionary (with months January to May as keys).

I have tried using the .concat and .append but I seem to be doing something wrong and it is sorting values.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it is sorting values"? You can use `.update` if they don't share common keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=update#dict.update) function:

```
a = {1: 2, 2: 3}
b = {3: 4, 4: 5}
a.update(b)
a
```

> `{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}`

---

P.S. Note that dictionaries in Python are unordered. You can't rely on the keys order. If you want to use the ordered dictionary, you should use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict) from collections module.

Comment: Note, that order is important for the OP and this solution will only officially work in python3.7+ where dicts are in insertion order.

Comment: I was updating my answer with more info about orders in this moment :)